# Initial and final objects of a category

Tags: category-theory

Let $\thicksim$ be an equivalence relation defined on a set $A.$
Assertion: "The quotient $A/{\thicksim}$ is universal with respect to the property of mapping $A$ to a set in such a way that equivalent elements have the same image." i.e., functions $A \xrightarrow{ \phi} Z$ with $Z$ being any set satisfying $a' \thicksim a'' \Rightarrow \phi(a') =\phi(a'').$ These morphisms are objects, $(\phi,Z)$ of a category. Morphisms $( \phi_1 , Z_1) \rightarrow ( \phi_2 , Z_2)$ are defined as commutative diagrams.

[image]

Question: Identify clearly the initial and final objects of this category.

I'm a beginner learning Category theory. I know the definitions of initial and final objects as defined as singletons of the corresponding $Hom$ sets. Is there an easier way to interpret universal property ? I'm finiding in difficult to even intutively think what that means. Any help in solving this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** What does $A/{\sim}$ being universal mean? Try to interpret $(\pi, A/{\sim})$ in your new category ($\pi\colon A\rightarrow A/{\sim}$ being the canonical projection). For the other object, it might help to identify the corresponding object in the category of sets.

Comment: I don't see, where it says what the actual universal property is. But this is not important anymore. 
For the final object, I can only repeat myself: What is the final object in the category of sets?

Comment: The final object in the category of sets is any one element set: from any set there is exactly one function, the constant, to a one element set. The universal property of $\pi:A\to A/\sim$ is a *rephrasing* of the claim that this is the initial object in the category given in the problem.